# mysql server replaces supplementary Unicode characters with a question mark (?)

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, mysql-5.6, utf8mb4, supplementary

I am using a Mysql 5.6.27 server and python as the application.
The database and tables are set to default of `utf32_general_ci` and the column type to `utf8mb4`. using *Anaconda Python 2.7* on Mac OS

In my program, I am opening the mysql connection with `charset='utf8mb4'`. Additionally I execute the below three statements after opening the connection.

```
self._cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
self._cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
self._cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")
```

My problem is that when I insert rows to the table, it replaces the supplementary unicode characters with a `?`. I have looked around for answers, and there doesn't seem to be any recommendations beyond what I have already implemented (as detailed in this question).

As an e.g. the unicode character `U+2620 'SKULL AND CROSSBONES'` was inserted as a proper unicode but the character `'FALLEN LEAF' (U+1F342)` got replaced by a `?`.

Not sure if the actual python code that leads to mysql insert is relevant, but I will put it in just in case.

Please help.

**--Python Code for function that calls mysql insert--**

```
def insert_multiple_to_table(self, alliance_data_list):
  list_tuple = []
  for data in data_list:
    dict_obj = dict.fromkeys(COLUMNS)
    for name, value in data.iteritems():
        if value == 'None':
          value = 'null'
        dict_obj[name] = value
    data_tuple = tuple(dict_obj[item] for item in COLUMNS)  #create an ordered list
    list_tuple.append(data_tuple)
  format_strings = " (" + ','.join(COLUMNS) + ") "
  insert_query = "insert into " + self._tblname + format_strings + " VALUES (" + ','.join(['%s'] * len(COLUMNS)) + ")"
  result = self._db.executemany(insert_query, list_tuple)
  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

For `fallen leaf`, you need utf8mb4, not just utf8.

Python needs `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Check that the column in the table is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Check with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

The connection should be something like

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS,
        db=DB_NAME, charset="utf8mb4", use_unicode=True)
```

(If that complains, switch to utf8; I am unclear whether that clause is aimed at MySQL or the outside world.)

See also [Python notes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python).

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is only needed if the source file itself contains unicode characters, it's completely irrelevant if the data in `list_tuple` comes from somewhere else. The interesting question would be if `list_tuple` contains `str` or `unicode` objects.

Comment: @mata the list_tuple has unicode objects. and as I mentioned other than the supplementary characters, everything else shows up fine (when print to Mac terminal as well as csv files that i save to disk for testing).

Comment: @Rick, my connection is all 'utf8mb4'.  but i havent tried the use_unicode flag. particularly since half the unicode are working fine. but will try and update.

Comment: If you still have troubles, edit your question to specify all the items I have pointed out (`CREATE TABLE`, connection string, where the character comes from, etc)